# Hadoop error "too many failed volumes" while running command to get file permissions : ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515

Tags: java, windows, hadoop

While running dfs on my window machine I am getting this error:

> ```
> -- file path: C:/hadoop/data/datanode
> 2020-05-05 11:44:59,230 WARN checker.StorageLocationChecker: Exception checking StorageLocation [DISK]file:/C:/hadoop/data/datanode
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.r`enter code here`unCommand(Shell.java:1009)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:902)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1227)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1321)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1303)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1343)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNonNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:726)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:717)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:678)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:233)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:141)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:116)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:239)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:52)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker$1.call(ThrottledAsyncChecker.java:142)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNonNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:766)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:717)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:678)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:233)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:141)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:116)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:239)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:52)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker$1.call(ThrottledAsyncChecker.java:142)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 2020-05-05 11:44:59,243 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
> org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
> ```

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: HAVE U GOT THE SOLUTION?